# Ajax request with multiple select box conditions

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database

First of all let me say that I'm just starting to learn, as a hobby, the basics of Web development: html, css, javascript and php.

I'm trying to implement a Web page with a database query and have encountered some dificulties:

If someone could enlighten me on which way to proceed it would be much appreciated.

I don't want you to write the whole code for me but yes show me some hints and clues.

I have a table with Id, items, price1, price2, and price3.

After a lot of searching I managed to load all the items dynamicaly on a select list and show (price1) on a div with an on change event based on the item selected with an ajax  call.

Now I need to update this price div based on two other select lists: one with 3 values (a,b,c) and the other one with (yes or no).

If select list 2 is (a) and select list 3 is (yes) the price to be displayed is (price2); If select list 2 is (b) and select list 3 is (yes) the price to be displayed is  (price3) and if select list 3 option is (no) than wich ever price was loaded must be dobled. All with ajax and regardless to the order of selections.

Hope I made myself clear.
I can load my code if needed.

Thanks in advance. 
Vasco

This is what I have so far:

Ajax.php

```
<?php
db connection variables


if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'price_1' => '', 'message' => 'no id given'));
    exit;
}

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    trigger_error("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'price_1' => '', 'message' => 'shit happened' . $e->getMessage()));
    exit;
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT price_1 FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result === false){
    trigger_error('Query failed: ' . $conn->errorInfo());
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'price_1' => '', 'message' => 'shit happened'));
    exit;
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'price_1' => $result['price_1'], 'message' => ''));
    exit;
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
Connection Variables
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test;charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    trigger_error("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
$query = "SELECT `id`, `items`, `price_1` FROM `table`";
$rows = $conn->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

       <script>
            function getPrice(id){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        if(jsonObj.success === true){
                            document.getElementById("price_1").value = jsonObj.price_1;
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("price_1").innerHTML = jsonObj.message;
                        }
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?id=" + id, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>



<div>

<h3>GET A QUOTE</h3>



    Item:
    <br>
    <select name="price" id="priceSelect" onchange="getPrice(this.value)">
        <option>Please select:</option>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['items'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br>

    size:
    <br>
<select name="price" id="sizeselectSelect" onchange="sizePrice(this.value)">
        <option>Please select:</option>
        <option value="1">size1</option>
        <option value="2">size2</option>
        <option value="3">size3</option>
    </select>

<br>
        double:
        <br>
        <select name="bouble" id="doubleprice" onchange="lastprice(this.value)">
        <option>Please select:</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
<br>
<br>
Total price:

    <input type="text" name="price_1[]" value="" id="price_1">&euro; 
    <p id="error"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could provide what have you done so far with code snippets it would be easier to understand what you're trying to achieve as it doesn't make sense right now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery a sit simplifies AJAX.

If the data isn't that large, I would do an ajax request on page load (to prevent tons of user wait time son ajax calls) and store the result into a javascript global/object.

If the page isn't meant to be refreshed at all, and the data is meant to be "live" then wait times could succumb, but you would just fire an ajax call when the user selects an option.

You can use a similar structure as this:

```
//bind event of select changing to a funciton that fires off the ajax
//the below avoids having to attach/unattach evenmt handlers on any dynamic elements
var body = jQuery("body");
body.on("change","#selectID",updatePriceFunction);

function updatePriceFunction() {
    loader.show();//unhide the loading animation 
    var optionChosen = jQuery("#selectID").find("option:selected").val();//this assumes the options have values that are identifies for that option to be sent to the ajaxEndpoint
      var payload = {selectedOption: optionChosen, otherData: otherValueNeeded}; //makes a javascript object with values to be sent to fetch the price
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: urlToAjaxEndpoint,//string
          data: payload,
          dataType: "json",
          traditional: true,
          success: getDataSuccess,
          error: ajaxErrorHandling,
          complete: function() {loader.hide();}//always hide the loading animation, even if ajax fails
      });

      //methods seperated (not inline in the above ajax call) as to allow for reuse

      function getDataSuccess(data){//data is the response form the server, parsed using jQuery JSON if the ajaxEndpoint server said the response type was JSON
        if(data.result == true) {
            //find the table area you wnat to update, and use the new value
            //data.result .....
        } else {
            //server returned value indicating operation was successful, such as if the combo was invalid or not, etc
            //data.message ....
        }
      }

      function ajaxErrorHandling(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){//jqXHR is the jquery xml html request object
            //ajax error connecting to endpoint / exception on response parsing
            var details = JSON.stringify(jqXHR, null, 4);
            console.error("Exception: "+errorThrown+" - Status: "+textStatus + " - XMLHTTPRequest:" + details);
            showAlertMessage("An error occurred");
      }
}

//this assumes the server returns a json object of the form:
//[
//  error: true/false,
//  message: "",
//  result: object
//]

//whatever the endpoint uses, you'll likely need to parse the payload object, and then create a json response
//be careful of special characters on the endpoint, as they can be "escaped" in the raw json and will throw a parse exception
```

This should be enough to get you started down the right path. 
PS: jQuery isn't NECESSARY, but it makes it a LOT easier.